# Python np.select does not obey my conditions, why?

Tags: python, pandas, margin

I have this part of code:

```
title = "Margin with minimal market price"

active_prods[title] = (active_prods['market min'] - active_prods['cost']) / active_prods['market min']

conditions = [
    (active_prods[title] < 0),
    (active_prods[title] >= 0) & (active_prods[title] <= 5),
    (active_prods[title] > 5) & (active_prods[title] <= 10)]
choices = ['1) <0', '2) <=5%', '3) <=10%']
active_prods['Margin type'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='4) >10%')
```

Long story short - I am trying to calculate my product margin and to give it some type depending on where in the interval it is. My code sets all <0 margins correctly, but everything above or equal to zero is set to second option:

> 2) <=5%

Somehow it only takes the first part of the second condition(which is >=0) and completely ignores the second part of the condition. The third condition is also completely ignored. Why is this happening?

Active_prods is pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another way to achieve it. you can use bin and cut the range into baskets.
see a mockup below:

```
import pandas as pd
active_prods = pd.DataFrame({'Margin':[0,-2,4,10,35,1,54]})
bins= [-100,0,6,11,100]
labels = ['1) <0','2) <=5%','3) <=10%','4) >10%']
active_prods['MarginType'] = pd.cut(active_prods['Margin'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
active_prods
```

see the result below:

```
Margin  MarginType
0   0   2) <=5%
1   -2  1) <0
2   4   2) <=5%
3   9   3) <=10%
4   35  4) >10%
5   1   2) <=5%
6   54  4) >10%
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `active_prods` is a Numpy array, I think your `&` is incorrect for combining logical arrays.

You probably want:

```
np.logical_and(active_prods[title] >= 0, active_prods[title] <= 5)
```

Comment: Active prods is a dataframe and 'active_prods[title]' is a column in it...